# Intersection of multiple lists with cross-tab format

Tags: python, list, pandas, intersection

I have a group of lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [1,2,4]
d = [1,3,6]
```

I want to get the **count of intersection of each two lists**, with the output displayed as a cross-tabulation, so that the columns and index are both a, b, c, d.

For instance, both 2 and 3 are common between `a` and `b`, so the count is 2 between them.

Comment: Pls provide a more clearer `output` for the whole scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = [2,3,4]
c = [1,2,4]
d = [1,3,6] 

l = [ i for i in [ ['a']+a, ['b']+b, ['c']+c, ['d']+d] ]
from itertools import combinations
print ([(i[0]+j[0], len(set(i).intersection(j))) for i,j in combinations(l, 2)])
#which is same as
print ([(j[0]+i[0], len(set(j).intersection(i))) for i,j in combinations(l, 2)])
```

Output:

```
[('ab', 2), ('ac', 2), ('ad', 2), ('bc', 2), ('bd', 1), ('cd', 1)]
[('ba', 2), ('ca', 2), ('da', 2), ('cb', 2), ('db', 1), ('dc', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting you to a crosstab format as you indicated in your question:

```
from itertools import permutations
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [1,2,4]
d = [1,3,6]

names = list('abcd')    
data = dict(zip(names, (a,b,c,d)))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,4), dtype=np.int8), index=data, columns=data)

for i, j in permutations(df.index, 2):
    df.loc[i, j] = len(set(data[i]).intersection(set(data[j])))

print(df)
   a  b  c  d
a  0  2  2  2
b  2  0  2  1
c  2  2  0  1
d  2  1  1  0
```

Ironically, I'm not all that sure [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) will work here but may very well stand corrected on that.